# AdWords SDK looks for System.Web reference in .net core app

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-ads-api

I have added the NuGet Google.AdWords 24.10.1 package to a .net core console app.
In the SDK documentation they say that .net core is supported.
The problem is that the library functions crash on first call with tho following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment' from
>   assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.":"System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment"}

I cant understand if this package is supported or not in the core app?

This line causes a crash:             `AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();`

Answer (score 0):

So my Adwords code was inside old .net project that was set to .net 4.6... Had to switch to .net 4.7.2 and reinstall all nugget packages.